# Opinions attributed to Gauss

Tags: math-history

In [this article](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9404229), Armand Borel writes the following:

> [...] In fact, during the next quarter century, we experienced a
>   tremendous development of pure mathematics, bringing solutions of
>   one fundamental problem after the other, unifications, etc., but
>   during all that time,] there was in some quarters some whining about
>   the dangers of the separation between pure math and applications to
>   sciences, and how the great nineteenth century mathematicians
>   cultivated both (conveniently ignoring some statements by none other
>   than Gauss which hardly support that philosophy.  [...]

Question: what statements by Gauss could he have meant?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/94886/gausss-views-on-pure-mathematics

Comment: Not really a mathematics question.